# For loop based on number of labels in target variable

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, variables, data-visualization

I am new to python and learning to work on a `for` loop for creating an automated bar chart. The below code is worked out for a target variable with 2 classes `(0 ,1)`. I am trying to create a `for` loop that can create `x0, x1, x2` and so on based on the number of classes in the target variable.

For example: If my Target variable has 4 classes, then I need `x0, x1, x2, x3` to be created with `Target == 0,1,2,3` for `x`s and also in the similar way I need the `trace1`, `trace2`, `trace3`, and `trace4` for 4 classes.

Could someone please help me with it?

```
from scipy.stats import skew
from scipy.stats import kurtosis

def plotBarCat(df,feature,target):
    x0 = df[df[target]==0][feature]
    x1 = df[df[target]==1][feature]

    trace1 = go.Histogram(
        x=x0,
        opacity=0.75
    )
    trace2 = go.Histogram(
        x=x1,
        opacity=0.75
    )

    data = [trace1, trace2]
    layout = go.Layout(barmode='overlay',
                      title=feature,
                       yaxis=dict(title='Count'
        ))
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

    py.iplot(fig, filename='overlaid histogram')

    def DescribeFloatSkewKurt(df,target):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
def plotBarCat(df,feature,target):
    # use set to get unique classes
    classes = set(df[target])
    # create list for traces
    data = []
    
    for c in classes:
        z = df[df[target] == c][feature]
        trace = go.Histogram(x=z, opacity=0.75)
        data.append(trace)

    layout = go.Layout(barmode='overlay',
                      title=feature,
                       yaxis=dict(title='Count'
        ))
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

    py.iplot(fig, filename='overlaid histogram')
```